# What does "Comparing constant with boolean expression is always true" warning mean?

Tags: c

What does this warning mean (`i` and `j` are not constants):

I have been trying to Google this but it does not give me any results.

> warning: comparison of constant 10 with boolean expression is
>         always true [-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
>
> ```
>  if ((0<=i<=10)&&(0<=j<=10)){
> ```

In my program, `i` and `j` are not constant values and they do change.

Answer (score 16):

In `C`, chaining of relational operators like this are not valid design. Thus,

```
 (0<=i<=10)
```

is not doing what you think it should be doing. it is getting evaluated as

```
((0<=i) <= 10 )
```

which is basically either

- `0 < = 10`, producing `1` (considered TRUE value)
- `1 < = 10`, also producing `1` (considered TRUE value)

sadly, both of which are way out than the expected path.

**Solution:** you need to break down your condtion check like

```
 (0 <= i) && ( i<=10)
```

Comment: OH i see :D Thank you so much! Silly me....Was trying hard to figure out why its not working....

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to understand what's going on in your statement at a deeper level.

`0<=i` is a boolean expression, it will become true or false.
The result of that expression is then compared with 10.

So you end up with `true <= 10` or `false <= 10`.

I think you meant to write

```
if ( ( 0 <= i ) && ( i <= 10 ) )
```

You cannot connect clauses together the way you did.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much :D OH yes this is very helpful, I didn't know the mechanism. Thank you alot appreciate it.

Comment: I suspect he wants to use `if ( ( 0 <= i) && (i <= 10))`

Comment: @RSahu yes thats what I want to use.

Comment: So I believe my full if statement should be : if ( ( ( 0 <= i) && (i <= 10))&&( ( 0 <= i) && (i <= 10)) )

Comment: Try `if ( ( ( 0 <= i) && (i <= 10))&&( ( 0 <= j) && (j <= 10)) )`

Answer (score 3):

The other answers have already explained the core problem. You can use:

```
if ( ( ( 0 <= i) && (i <= 10)) && ( ( 0 <= i) && (i <= 10)) )
```

to resolve your problem.

My recommendation will be to wrap that logic in a function.

```
int isInRange(int x, int lower, int upper)
{
   return (lower <= x && x <= upper);
}
```

and use

```
if ( isInRange(i, 0, 10) && isInRange(j, 0, 10) )
```

Comment: +1 Thank you very much :) I can't understand one thing : Why is it that you recommend using a function rather than the previous way? Is there a particular reason I should be aware of?

Comment: @TheArtist. Couple of reasons. 1) You avoid repeating the code that captures the logic. 2) You define the name of the operation, which makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the expression can be evaluated at compile time, and that the evaluation will not be compiled because it's `true` (ie. non-zero) at compile time.

Usually this happened to me when I accidentally used `&&` instead of `&`. Which is not the case here of course, but it gives the same error message.

Also note that `gcc` makes a distinction between `logical` and `bitwise`:

`Logical` means `bool` which is either `0` meaning `false` or non-zero meaning `true` and the operator that yields these is `&&` with keyword `and`.

`Bitwise` means `boolean logic` and the operator is `&` with keyword `bitand`.

`&&` Always yields a `bool`, which is true unless it's `0`. If operating on `bool`s they're equivalent, but on anything else `&` and `&&` test different things ie. "Is it nonzero" vs "return only the matching bits".