# Output of this C program i can't understand

Tags: c

I am revising C again and was making some test programs. At one program I was checking a condition which was translating ino this condition.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
if(0 <= 3000.000000 <= 2000.00){  //this is the condition
printf("3000 is less than 2000, whoa.. \n");
}
return 0;
}
```

The output is always this print string. I can't understand why.

P.S

I am testing the middle value, i.e 3000.000000 here, but it can be some variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Comparing constant with boolean expression is always true" warning mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807947/what-does-comparing-constant-with-boolean-expression-is-always-true-warning-me)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition is parsed like this:

```
if((0 <= 3000.000000) <= 2000.00){
```

The first part, `(0 <= 3000.000000)`, is true, and evaluates to `1` in the comparison with `2000.00`. And `1 <= 2000.00` is true.

If you're trying to test whether a value `a` lies between two values `b` and `c` or is equal to either, then you need an expression along the lines of

```
(a >= b) && (a <= c)
```

Comment: Too fast XD. I can't post my answer before you and I can't comment to tell you about your typo before you correct it.

Comment: I meant the first edit where you changed `false` to `true`.

Comment: @Arc676 Yep, I got that one before your comment arrived, so I wasn't sure if you were referring to that. Thanks.

Comment: if((0 <= 3000.000000) && (3000.000000 <= 2000.000000)) is this the correct way to test this condition??

Comment: @MloBootloader How could anyone know? You haven't specified what you are actually trying to test.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting caught by the fact that in C, booleans are integers: either `0` or `1`.

So that line is interpreted left-to-right: First `0 <= 3000`, which is true so it ends up as `1`. Then that value is fed into the next half, `(1) <= 2000`, which is obviously true.

Answer (score 3):

It will prints the string in printf.

Because the condition is static.

The 0 is always less than 30000.000000. For the next condition the output of the first condition returns 1. it checks using the 1.

The second condition checking is 1 <= 2000.00. This condition is also true.

So, only this prints the string.

Answer (score 0):

the first condition evaluates to 1 as output and further 1<2000 is checked which is also true.So,the string is printed.